# READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-file, android-external-storage

I'm trying to republish my app for API level 26 as per Play Store requirements but I am getting null back from this:

```
File[] files = directory.listFiles();
```

I understand this is because I need to check permissions at runtime now. I have inserted this code at the start of the activity's onCreate to do that.

```
// check permissions
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        // Permission is not granted
        this.finish();
    }
```

But it does not recognise READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. Strangely it does recognise WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.
I saw many responses saying the wrong import is to blame, so I now have this:

```
import android.Manifest;
```

In the manifest itself I have this, inside the Manifest tag but outside the Application tag.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I am working in Eclipse/ADT and have updated the SDK and support package. Any idea what is going on here?

Comment: try Rebuild/Clean Project, Invalidate Cache & Restart.

Comment: I don't know the reason why this happens, but READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is just a String constant, so you can use "android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" string instead of it

Comment: OK I tried moving the project to a whole new workspace and it made no difference. I also tried requesting the permission just using "android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" as suggested. This returns -1 i.e. it doesn't have this permission.

Comment: Eclipse ADT is no longer supported. Could be an issue with the tooling. I think it's worth the effort converting the project to Android Studio. http://tools.android.com/recent/eclipseadtbundleupdated

Answer (score -1):

I had not updated the build target in the Project Properties.
If anyone else faces this situation that is the solution.